# Unused instance variables in abstract class

Tags: java, class, oop, abstract-class

I'm having a problem in my abstract class and its subclass. `ActionDeck` is a subclass of `Deck` which contains a no-argument constructor for `ActionDeck`, but whenever I get `NullPointerException` for the deque and array list instance variables my superclass has. It also marks it as **unused** in VScode. I'm not sure if I am implementing it correctly. What is wrong with my code?

Deck.java

```
abstract class Deck<C> {

    protected Deque<C> deck;
    protected ArrayList<C> temp;
    
    public Deck () {
        Deque<C> deck = new ArrayDeque<>();
        ArrayList<C> temp = new ArrayList<>();  
    }
```

ActionDeck.java

```
public class ActionDeck extends Deck<ActionCard> {

    public ActionDeck() {
        super();
    }
```

So when I tried to add something into the arraylist in `ActionDeck` it spits out an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.ArrayList.add(Object)" because "this.temp" is null
        at ActionDeck.generateDeck(ActionDeck.java:26)
        at Board.initializeData(Board.java:30)
        at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please include the code for the `generateDeck()` method, which is where the actual exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The `Deck` constructor isn't initializing the members - it's declaring two local variables which hide the members and initializing them. Remove the type declarations on those lines, and you'll get the behavior you expected:

```
public Deck () {
    deck = new ArrayDeque<>();
    temp = new ArrayList<>();  
}
```

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that! Thank you so much, it works again.